# is Charts 3.0.1 support drill down feature?

Tags: ios, charts

I am using Charts 3.0.1 library. but I didn't get any documentation which will get this library support to drill down feature or not. If yes please suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, for that we can use chart view delegate method 'chartValueSelected'.